# Laravel-Excel: How to open an xls, set some input cells and read the result cell in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel-8, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I'm working with Laravel and I installed Laravel-Excel package.

How can I set some cells and read the results of some formulas from other cell?
Is that possible with this package/plain php?

I'm ready to switch to Phpspreadsheet too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which php excel package are you using?

Comment: Laravel Excel uses PHPSpreadsheet under the hood. It's an excellent tool if you are using Laravel. Post some code showing what you have tried so we can get a better idea of what you want to do.

Comment: @AnisurRahman I was using Laravel-Excel, but I moved to PhpSpreadsheet